# What replenishes the lunar atmosphere?

Tags: the-moon, planetary-atmosphere

It is often said that the Moon doesn't have an atmosphere. But there is an envelope of gas surrounding the Moon, albeit a thin one, so the Moon has at least an exosphere.

The Moon doesn't have its own magnetic field and has comparatively low gravity, so any atmosphere should be rapidly stripped away by solar winds and thermal escape. For there to still be an atmosphere, there must be some mechanism that that replenishes it.

What replenishes the lunar atmosphere, to compensate for loss from solar winds and thermal escape?